# Insert issue Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 2

Tags: sql-server-2012

General newbie SQL question probs...

Why doesn't this work - or, what does this mean?

```
INSERT INTO test_db.dbo.Customers2
  SELECT FirstName
  FROM jas_test_db.dbo.Customers
  WHERE (Customers.FirstName = Firstname)
```

I get:

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should supply column name for Customers2:

```
INSERT INTO test_db.dbo.Customers2(**Firstname**)

SELECT FirstName

FROM jas_test_db.dbo.Customers

WHERE (Customers.FirstName = Firstname)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to **always** explicitly specify which columns you want to insert into:

```
INSERT INTO test_db.dbo.Customers2(FirstName)  -- <-- specify the columns you want to insert into!
  SELECT FirstName
  FROM jas_test_db.dbo.Customers
  WHERE (Customers.FirstName = Firstname)
```

If you don't do this, you have to provide values for **all** columns, in the exact order in which they are defined in the table